# Firebase Crashlytics links from mail, redirect to error-page, due to wrong Chrome user

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, crashlytics

Setup:

- having a firebase project with crashlytics active
- receive mails for crashes
- try to open the crash from the link within the mail

Example link: `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/xxx-8c64/crashlytics/app/android:com.example.project/issues/3fgdfgfdg9e86f653d84df9fdfdfdf3?time=last-seven-days`

*I have multiple accounts in chrome. One is my private, one is my work account.
My main account is the private one. (`/u/0`)*

**Now, once I try to open the link**

**result**: get redirected to wrong user `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/`

[image]

**expected result**: asking which account I want to use to open the link

My current workaround is to stop loading the link in the middle and replacing the `u/0` with `u/1` and let chrome continue. This will load the link correctly. But it will not always work and is super cumbersome.

Is there anything I can do? Do some of you face the same problem?

*(Besides logging in with my work account. No - I don't want to log out from my main and switch forth and back all the time)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a way, although I would love to hear a better one.

Using a redirect chrome extension. **Redirector**

[github Link](https://github.com/bendavis78/chrome-extension-redirector)

[Chrome Extension Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/pajiegeliagebegjdhebejdlknciafen)

**RegEx:**

From: `^https://console\.firebase\.google\.com/u/./(.*)`

to: `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/$1`